# How to compare two files with without it doing it line-by-line or ignoring words it has already seen before? (Bash Linux)

Tags: bash, grep, diff

So I am trying to compare two files. text1.txt and text2.txt and put the difference between the two files in the file text3.txt

My issue is that I cannot find a way to make it eighter not check line-by-line or have it say that the difference between

`text1=  and text2=    outout=  instead of wanted output=
Hi           Hi        Bye                 Hi
Hi                                         Bye
Bye`

The line where it does what is show above is: `grep -v -f text1.txt text2.txt > text3.txt`

if i try using comm or diff I run into the issue where it only checks line-by-line, for instance: `comm -2 -3 text1.txt text2.txt > text3.txt`
gives when I change the order of the lines:

`text1=  and  text2=    output=   instead of  Wanted output=
Bye          Hi        Bye                   Yay
Hi           Bye       Hi
Yay                    Yay`

In short I am looking for a way to check for the difference in words without them having to be on the same line, which which also only compares every word once instead of it saying there is no difference between the same word 1 time and the same word 3 times.
I hope my ramblings make some sense and I thank you in advance for your help.

(This is all with bash linux)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Maybe `diff --ignore-all-space` can be useful for this -- have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah that seems to do the job. Thanks! :)
is there a way to remove the non word parts of the output though?
Like the `36,39c38,40` and the `---` that are put in between the words in the output?

Comment: I don't know right now but there are lots of options to `diff` -- you can look at `man diff` and see if you find some option that lets you do what you want.